# Is this a misprint or not?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am currently reading Mathematical physics by Eugene Butkov and on the section discussing scalar potentials, it gives a proof showing that $\operatorname{grad} \phi = u$. At the very end, it says that $u_{x} = \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial z}$ and not $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}$. Please help. [here is the specific section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22u8Z.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. Only $u_x = \partial \varphi / \partial x$ makes sense there.